# Modulo arithmetic and sum of arbitrary powers of a primitive root of unity.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic, roots-of-unity, primitive-roots

Prove that if $w$ is a primitive nth root of unity, then

$1 + w^k + (w^k)^2 + (w^k)^3 + \cdots + (w^k)^{n-1} =0$ iff $k \neq 0$ mod $n$.

Sorry for the terrible formatting. Also, I don't know anything about groups and rings, so please keep the answer as elementary as possible! Thanks.

Note : $k$ is a non-zero integer.

Comment: This is the sum of a finite geometric progression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\ldots+x^{n-1}) = 1 - x^n$.

Comment: Hmm.. Then 1+x+x^2.. +x^n-1 = 1-x^n /1-x
We replace x by w^k

So 1+w^k .... = 1-w^nk / 1-x 

1+w^k.... =0 iff 1-w^nk = 0, which is only possible if w^nk = 1.
But w^nk = 1 if and only if k is a multiple of n, i.e k = 0 mod n because w is a primitive root.

Comment: Indeed, as long as $x \ne 1$.

Comment: Isn't that contradicting k =/=0 mod n?

Comment: Nevermind, I see what I did wrong. Thanks!